# Regex to find a specific word between two other specific words

Tags: regex

when inspecting content of email body I want to detect when a distribution list name contains "DL" in the "To" field or the "CC" field but not in the subject.

Basically i want my text (DL) detected when found between the closest "To:" and the closest "Subject".

The best I can do is the following  but it detects everything from the very first instance of "To:" with a subsequent DL until the very last instance of "Subject"

```
(?<=To: )(?s:.)*?( DL | DL-)(?s:.)*?(?=Subject:)
```

expected results: "DL-" from DL-Musketeers but not the "DL" in the subject line if the distribution list wasn't present

```
From: Mouse, Mickey <JMouse@Disney.​com<mailto:JMouse@​Disney.com>>
Sent: Thursday, May 26, 2022 8:14 AM
To: Mouse, Minnie <DMouse@Disney.c​om<mailto:DMouse@Disney.com>>  
Cc: Disney, Joseph R <JDisney@Disney.co​m<mailto:JDisney@Disney.com>> DL-Musketeers@Disney.com 
Subject: RE: DL commission
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use the `?s` flag, that allows `.` to match newlines. By default `.*` will stay on the same line.

Comment: Why not just `^(?:To|Cc):.*? DL[ -]` see https://regex101.com/r/1hYfn7/1

Comment: Somehow hard to read, however if you are using PHP/PCRE and just want to skip the Subject line, you can try e.g.: [`Subject:.*(*SKIP)(*F)|DL-`](https://regex101.com/r/c3XzA5/1)

Comment: @Barmar - thanks for the formatting assist and solution recommendation. I took your suggestion, modified the code and believe this to be my solution.  Testing now. <pre>(?<=To:)(.)*?(DL |DL-)(?s:.)*?(?=Subject:)|(?<=Cc:)(.)*?(DL |DL-)(?s:.)*?(?=Subject:)<code>

Comment: If you found a solution you should post it as an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution with help from @Barmar.
What I'm using is:

```
(?<=To:)(.)*?( DL | DL-)(?s:.)*?(?=Subject:)|(?<=Cc:)(.)*?( DL | DL-)(?s:.)*?(?=Subject:)
```